# convert json string to case class object from given json string and type of case class

Tags: json, scala, jackson, gson, case-class

Requirement is to convert json string to case class object in scala given jsonString and the type of the case class.

I have tried Gson and jackson libraries, but not able to solve the given requirment.

```
package eg.json

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

case class Person(name : String, age : Int)

case class Address(street : String, buildingNumber : Int, zipCode : Int)

case class Rent(amount : Double, month : String)

//there are many other case classes

object JsonToObject extends LazyLogging{

  import logger._

  def toJsonString(ref : Any) : String = {
    val gson = new Gson()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(ref)
    jsonString
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val person = Person("John", 35)
    val jsonString = toJsonString(person)

    //here requirement is to convert json string to case class instance, provided the type of case class instance

    val gsonObj = toInstanceUsingGson( jsonString, Person.getClass )
    debug(s"main : object deserialized using gson : $gsonObj")

    val jacksonObj = toInstanceUsingJackson( jsonString, Person.getClass )
    debug(s"main : object deserialized using gson : $jacksonObj")

  }

  def toInstanceUsingGson[T](jsonString : String, caseClassType : Class[T]) : T = {

    val gson = new Gson()
    val ref = gson.fromJson(jsonString, caseClassType)
    ref
  }

  def toInstanceUsingJackson[T](jsonString : String, caseClassType : Class[T]) : T = {

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val ref = mapper.readValue(jsonString, caseClassType)
    ref
  }
}
```

Output of execution of above code is :-

```
01:32:52.369 [main] DEBUG eg.json.JsonToObject$ - main : object deserialized using gson : Person
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class eg.json.Person$), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"name":"John","age":35}"; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: eg.json.Person$["name"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at eg.json.JsonToObject$.toInstanceUsingJackson(JsonToObject.scala:49)
    at eg.json.JsonToObject$.main(JsonToObject.scala:34)
    at eg.json.JsonToObject.main(JsonToObject.scala)
```

Kindly suggest, how to achieve this using gson or jackson, or suggest some other library with sample example.

Above simplified problem is on github :-

https://github.com/moglideveloper/JsonToScalaObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jackson you can do it like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
//this line my be needed depending on your case classes
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
```

I think it is really clean with Jackson lib.
The usage is like this:

```
val json: String = ???
val personObject: Person = fromJson[Person](json)
```

Comment: How, I will pass Person, for fromJson[Person](json). because method that convert jsonString to object can bes passed json string for any case class. how to make this generic

Comment: @mogli it is generic, you pass any case class, I just put an example on how to use it.

Comment: ohk, i got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using circe by Cats.

- add circe to your project (https://circe.github.io/circe/ - Quick Start).
- create a case class that represent what you want to build from your json.
- declare a decoder

https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html
https://github.com/circe/circe

```
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.syntax._

case class DataToDecode(name : String,
                        age : Int,
                        street : String,
                        buildingNumber : Int,
                        zipCode : Int, 
                        amount : Double, 
                        month : String)
object DataToDecode{
implicit val dataToDecode: Decoder[DataToDecode] = deriveDecoder

def decodeData(data: Json) : DataToDecode {
  data.as[DataToDecode].right.get
  }
}
```

nice example [here](https://edward-huang.com/scala/tech/soft-development/etl/circe/2019/11/28/6-quick-tips-to-parse-json-with-circe/)

Comment: How, I will pass DataToDecode, for data.as[DataToDecode].right.get. because method that convert jsonString to object can be passed json string for any case class. how to make this generic

Comment: is there a way to make decodeData method generic for any case class

Comment: you can create a case class of case classes - but you have to create a decoder for each case class and include it in the final case class companion object .

Comment: ohk, i got it now. Thanks